# How do I use MigratorScriptingDecorator in Entity Framework code first?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have problems using the [`MigratorScriptingDecorator.ScriptUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.infrastructure.migratorscriptingdecorator.scriptupdate%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) in Entity Framework 4.3.1.

When specifying sourceMigration and targetMigration only my initial migration gets written, the rest of my migrations become empty.

I have entered a bug report on Microsoft Connect containing reproducing code.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/731111/migratorscriptingdecorator-in-entity-framework-migrations-does-not-respect-sourcemigration-and-targetmigration

I expect `MigratorScriptingDecorator.ScriptUpdate("from", "to")` to behave exactly like the corresponding PM command

```
PM> Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration from -TargetMigration to
```

Should ScriptUpdate be equivalent to `Update-Database -Script`?
Are there any other ways of generating update scripts from code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted on the linked Microsoft Connect issue the problem was a reuse of the same `DbMigrator` on several `MigratorScriptingDecorator`s.

The original code was

```
DbMigrator efMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
var pendingMigrations = efMigrator.GetLocalMigrations().ToList();
pendingMigrations.Insert(0, "0");
foreach (var migration in pendingMigrations.Zip(pendingMigrations.Skip(1), Tuple.Create))
{
    var sql = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(efMigrator).ScriptUpdate(migration.Item1, migration.Item2); // <-- problem here, the efMigrator is reused several times
    Console.WriteLine("Migration from " + (migration.Item1 ?? "<null> ") + " to " + (migration.Item2 ?? "<null> "));
    Console.WriteLine(sql);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
}
```

the `MigratorScriptingDecorator` should be instantiated outside the loop like this:

```
DbMigrator efMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
var pendingMigrations = efMigrator.GetLocalMigrations().ToList();
pendingMigrations.Insert(0, "0");
var scriptMigrator = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(efMigrator); // <-- now only one MigratorScriptingDecorator is created for the DbMigrator
foreach (var migration in pendingMigrations.Zip(pendingMigrations.Skip(1), Tuple.Create))
{
    var sql = scriptMigrator.ScriptUpdate(migration.Item1, migration.Item2);
    Console.WriteLine("Migration from " + (migration.Item1 ?? "<null> ") + " to " + (migration.Item2 ?? "<null> "));
    Console.WriteLine(sql);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
}
```