# Run Nuget commands in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, nuget

So pre-amble, I need to generate sql scripts for all the EF migrations within a solution I have.  I could do this manually through the Package Manager Console but to be honest, I'd rather write some code to do this for me than do it manually.

I have created a console app that uses reflection to find all the migration classes (code-first) within my project file and to order them correctly.  I now need to call the nuget command;

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase -TargetMigration: MyFirstMigration
```

then call it again with slightly modified syntax to generate each Up script in turn for each migration script.

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: MyFirstMigration -TargetMigration: MySecondMigration
```

Then I need to call them all again in reverse order to generate the Down scripts.

Does anyone or can anyone point me in the direction of how I might go about this?  I found this link http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/246688 that tells you how to call the Install-Package command but I don't know how to load the relevant one for EntityFramework

Comment: You should definitely read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701781/how-do-i-use-migratorscriptingdecorator-in-entity-framework-code-first The `Update-Database -Script` uses the same approach which means you can bypass it and use the `MigratorScriptingDecorator` directly.

Comment: As an aside, you can create a single, idempotent script that will test each migration one by one and apply the missing ones: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#idempotent    To generate the script from code see http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Comment: Wiktor Zychla - Thanks, thats just what I needed, a lot easier that trying to call the powershell script!

Comment: Ok got that working, now generated all the Up scripts but now I need to generate the Down scripts.  When I call Script.Update("v3","v2") it throws a wobbly with "Scripting the downgrade between two specified migrations is not supported."  Any pointers?